# pull to refresh not working in collection view when collection view have no data in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad-2

This is my refresh control in worldview method.

```
    self.colView.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    self.colView.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    self.colView.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.colView.refreshControl addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(refresh)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 9):

Please try this code. Collection view lost our height.

```
self.colView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

Comment: please tell me about problem

Comment: dude,it is awesome

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, Just you have to move tableview at top and set some frame before adding it to collectionview. This will work even if your collection view content view have 0 frame size:

```
 -(void)addPullToRefressToTableView {

    UIView *refreshView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 0, 0)];
    [self.tableView insertSubview:refreshView atIndex:0];

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadDatas) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    NSMutableAttributedString *refreshString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull To Refresh"];
   [refreshView addSubview:refreshControl];
}
```